# SEO of gallery deeplinks

Tags: seo, images, photo-gallery

if I have a gallery, say `2013/01/01/new-feature` and each image is indexable and can be shared:

```
2013/01/01/new-feature/slide1
2013/01/01/new-feature/slide2
```

Each slide will have an individual title+description, but this also means that the "Body text" of the each deeplink will always be the same.

Do I have to set `<h1>` for each deeplink to the title of each picture and will the duplicate body text on each slide deeplink hurt SEO?

Answer (score 2):

If the text is too similar, then Google are likely to assume the pages are the same and only list one of them.  It won't get you a penalty, but you might want to consider adding a canonical tag back to the main gallery page to make sure they treat that as the priority page to index.

As for H1s, they are good for semantic HTML, but there is not much evidence they do anything for SEO any more.  For semantic HTML, it sounds sensible to place the image title in the H1 tag.